# Combing two files with binary format

Tags: c, binary, fopen, fwrite, fseek

I wrote this code to test to combine two files:

```
 long getFileSize(char *filename)
{
     FILE* fp=fopen(filename,"rb");
     fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
     long size=ftell(fp); 
     fclose(fp); 
     return size;   
}



 long lengthA = getFileSize(argv[1]);
   long lengthB = getFileSize(argv[2]);
   printf("sizeof %s is:%d\n",argv[1],lengthA);
   printf("sizeof %s is %d\n",argv[2],lengthB);

   void *pa;
   void *pb;
   FILE* fp=fopen(argv[1],"rb");
   fread(pa,1,lengthA,fp);
   fclose(fp);
   FILE* fpn=fopen(argv[2],"rb");
   fread(pb,1,lengthB,fpn);
   fclose(fpn);
   printf("pointerA is:%p;pointerB is:%p\n",pa,pb);

   FILE *ff=fopen("test.pack","wb");
   fwrite(pa,1,lengthA,ff);
   fwrite(pb,1,lengthB,ff);
   fclose(ff);

   long lengthFinal = getFileSize("test.pack");

   printf("Final size:%i\n",lengthFinal);
```

however I don't know if the data is equal to the returned value from getFileSize,the console print clearly says something wrong with it,but I can't figure it out:

```
sizeof a.zip is:465235
sizeof b.zip is 107814
pointerA is:0x80484ec;pointerB is:0x804aff4
Final size:255270
```

since I know the length of each file,I can then use fseek to restore them right? that's the idea I was thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*pa` and `*pb` need to point to some memory where the file content shall be read to.

So, do a `malloc` for these two buffers with `lengthA*sizeof(char)` and `lengthB*sizeof(char)` and pass these allocated buffers to `fread`:

```
pa = malloc(lengthA*sizeof(char));
pb = malloc(lengthB*sizeof(char));
...
fread(pa,sizeof(char),lengthA,fp);
...
fread(pb,sizeof(char),lengthB,fpn);
```

Furthermore, `fread` returns the number of items actually read. Also check this!

Excerpt from [`man fread`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread):

> **fread()** and **fwrite()** return the number of items successfully read or written (i.e., not the number of characters). If an error occurs, or the end-of-file is reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero).

Answer (score 2):

Note that there's no real reason to load *both* source files into memory at once. Also, it's potentially very memory-inefficient to do so, since you're really reading all of the files in, and then all you do is write the contents out again.

A better algorithm, in my opinion, would be:

```
let C = a reasonable buffer size, say 128 KB
let B = a static buffer of C bytes
let R = the output file, opened for binary write
for each input file F:
  open F for binary read
  repeat
    let N be the number of bytes read, up to a maximum of C
    if N > 0
      write N first bytes of B into R
  until N = 0
  close F
close R
```

This does away with the need to allocate buffers dynamically, you could just do `char C[B]` and have `#define B (128 << 10)`.

The above assumes that reading from a file which has no more bytes to deliver returns 0 bytes.

Also note that by doing away with the need to load the entire file, you *also* no longer need to open each input file an extra time just to seek to the end in order to compute the file's size.

Answer (score 1):

`pa` and `pb` are not pointing to valid memory.

```
char* pa = malloc(lengthA * sizeof(char));
char* pb = malloc(lengthB * sizeof(char));
```

Remember to `free()` when no longer required.

Check all return values from functions `fopen()`, `fread()`, `fwrite()`, etc.